# Our client trying to move the Azure sql server from one resource group to another

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-migrate, azure-subscription

Our client trying to move the Azure SQL database resources from one resource group to another . The Azure SQL server having around 1600 databases. 4 Elastic pool have exist and databases segregated into 500+500+500+100 (1600 databases).

When our client moving the server to another resource group , he getting below error.

Error : The number write requests for subscription exceeded the limit of 1200 for the interval(1:00:00). Please wait for 303seconds(code:subscription requests throttled)

I know due to the maximum threshold reached, the error got triggered. Is there way to achieve our client requirement to move the Azure SQL server from one to another resource group.

Answer (score 0):

You can try other methods to copy the databases to another resource group.

1. **Bacpac file:** You can export bacpac from one Azure SQL DB and import it to another.

   [Export bacpac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export)

   [Import bacpac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import?tabs=azure-powershell)
2. **Using Azure Data Factory:** You can use ADF to copy to and from Azure SQL Database in different resource group.

   [Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database?tabs=data-factory)